# MSI and ClickOnce hybrid installer

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, clickonce

Currently I have this scenario on my work. We are almost ready to deploy an image of Windows OS that includes some additional software.

I need to provide installers (MSI) of developed software but with the condition that this installer will install first the software and then the software behaviors as a clickonce deployed software.

I try to find any information on how to achieve this requirement, without succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround to achieve a installer that "install" a clickonce application.
Actually the installer creates a desktop shortcut referencing a .bat file that starts the .application from the server and after load the application and removes the desktop icon.

The bat file is simple:

```
del "%userprofile%\Desktop\{MyApplicationName}.lnk"
rundll32 user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
start \\ServerPath\MyApplicationClickOnceInstaller.application
```

The first line is responsible for deleting the shortcut from user desktop.

The second one is responsible for refreshing the user desktop.

Finally, the last one opens the .application file from the server.

Just put this .bat file as a file in the installer and create a shortcut that opens it.